# Vue: mostrar y ocultar modal tras multiples await

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal, async-await, frontend

Tengo un componente en Vue con la función setShowLoading que muestra un modal de un spinner, con el código que esta debajo, pero el modal apenas aparece un segundo y antes incluso de que concluyan las funciones de los await, se deja de ver (directamente pasa a la función de la linea final con el false). Alguna idea sobre cómo podría solucionar esto y que el spinner se vea hasta que terminen su tarea los await?

````
async importFile(event){

 this.setShowLoading(true);
 try 
 {
  ...
  await ....
  await ....
  ...
 }
 catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
  this.setShowLoading(false);
 }
 this.setShowLoading(false);
}```
````

Comment: Acaso tendrás una excepción y esté entrando en el catch?

Comment: @dfvc lo verifique y en la consola no aparece ningun error. Tengo la sospecha que debe ser porque se trata quizas de una funcion asincronica y que hay varios await, pero no se me ocurre otra razon, o como poder solucionarlo si fuera eso